# VB.net Missing Data

Tags: vb.net, corruption

I didn't really know how to title this error but yeah, I used the quick replace function in vb and replaced "comp" instead of "comp." now I have a massive error, my designer isn't loading (it included the word comp) and I need to find and add the word comp back to where it is required. The error is

"The class frmuterDetails can be designed, but is not the first class in the file. Visual Studio requires that designers use the first class in the file. Move the class code so that it is the first class in the file and try loading the designer again. "

[image: The design window for the effected form.]

If I could go back to an earlier stage of my work that would be good too.

I have tried not saving and closing and reopening, didn't work for some reason it auto saved.

Ctrl + Z didn't work either it did up to a point but it didn't fix this error.

Comment: Have you thought of simply opening the designer file and writing `comp` where it is required?

Comment: Try a right click on the folder containing the project and see if Previous Versions is present. If so use it to go back to an earlier point in time. Restore is your only real option.

Answer (score 0):

smaller issue than I thought I changed "frmComputerDetails" at the top to "frmmuterDetails" and then relaunched the project the designer worked but then of course things that called "frmComputerDetails" didn't so I changed the first class from "frmmuterDetails" back to "frmComputerDetails" and it works as normal.

:)